# How do you say if something is as hard as something else?

Tags: grammaticality, comparatives

Today I wanted to say that buying a car for me is as hard as choosing a dish in a restaurant and I actually meant that I am picky on buying a car just like my eating habit. But I stuck in the middle of my talk and couldn't choose the right word. Now my question is if the following sentence is correct and how a native English speaker would say that:

> I am as picky in buying a car as I am in eating

Comment: Typically we would use "about" instead of "in" there: "I am as picky *about* buying a car as I am *about* eating."

Comment: Not an answer, but I get the feeling that you are _not_ very picky about your car. (Because most people I know do chose very quickly ad easily what they want to eat but they may spend weeks or months deciding on a car) Is that indeed the intended meaning?

Comment: Thanks Robusto. @oerkelens I guess I was trying to be a bit funny because we were talking about buying a car and I said I only have 2 options and can't think of any other brand

Comment: Your listener would need to understand that you are a picky eater in order to glean your intended meaning.

Comment: I find buying a car as difficult / demanding as deciding where to go for my holidays.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence does make sense; however, strictly speaking, it should read:

> I am as picky about buying a car as I am (about) eating.

Notice the change from "in" to "about". The "about" enclosed in brackets is not necessary and is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: There is a difference between being picky about eating and being picky eating, ie picky [when actually] eating. In the first case, one may avoid a certain restaurant; in the second, one may avoid the over-salted chowder one is served.